# How to avoid new pages in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

Sometime, my text rendering is:

BEGIN OF THE SENTENCE -- NEW PAGE(S) FULL OF PICTURES -- END OF THE SENTENCE

How can I manage to avoid this behavior and made this problematic sentence starting at the top of the new page ?

Comment: The general topic is "widows" and "orphans" (also known to TeX as "clubs." Search for "widow penalty" and "club penalty."

Comment: Also, you can forbid pages full of pictures over specific regions.  See \FloatBarrier (placeins package).

Comment: Welcome! Just be careful what you wish for ....